# Sharepoint date picker control

Tags: datepicker

Can someone please tell me how can I highlight certain dates in the date picker control when the calendar part is clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The SharePoint Date Picker control does not support this.  You can, however, use the jQuery Date Picker control instead to allow more functionality.  See http://www.notesfor.net/post/2010/02/04/SharePoint-DateTime-field-with-jQuery.aspx for one example.